# How could I configure an ide to run a verifone application?

Tags: project, verifone

I work with verifone applications but the project we use is in a very old win xp vm, does anyone know how I could configure an ide in win10?

Comment: Did you try to install verifone sdk on Windows 10?
According to verifone site, newest sdk require Windows 10 Enterprise and Android Studio 3.4.x or 3.5

Answer (score 0):

you need to sign in/out [Verifone Developer network](https://www.verifonedevnet.com/verifone/devnet/dnHome.do) in order to gather the development kit and other stuff(like documentation).